# What do the +X numbers at the end of trainer names mean?

Tags: terminology, cheats

For the context of this question, a "[trainer](http://vgstrategies.about.com/od/strategyglossary/g/Trainers.htm)" is a program that modifies the memory state of a game that is currently running.

From what I have noticed, trainers usually have a number like +3 or +4 or +10, etc., at the end of their name. What do those numbers stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The amount of features the trainer has. A +2 trainer might have *infinite health* and *infinite ammo* While a +3 might also come with a *infinite skill points* option.